# 1 hour connection Domestic to International flight in Detroit DTW

Tags: usa, transit, dtw

In November 2023 I'm taking a cruise from Los Angeles to Miami through the Panama Canal.

From Miami I have a domestic flight with Delta to Detroit (DTW). In Detroit I only have one hour to catch my international flight back home to Amsterdam.

Is that enough time? How long will it take to get from the Domestic to the International area from the airport?

Comment: Is this on a single ticket? Personally, I would not have booked that?

Comment: Most US airlines consider an hour to be a sufficient connection time for domestic-domestic or domestic-international connections at most airports for single-ticket purposes. Thanks to the way that Delta banks connections at hubs like DTW, it's not uncommon to have connections there in the 45-90 minute range. (Other airlines do the same thing, but not at DTW, which is only a hub for Delta.)

Comment: Which terminals in DTW? There are 2 major terminals, miles apart.  Is the itinerary all on 1 single ticket and from a first line carrier who will take responsibility for a connection problem not your fault? If you booked these as separate tickets, there's a Buddy's pizza about 10 miles away in Dearborn on US-12, so you can drown your sorrows in the best pizza in the world. It's not far from Greenfield Village & Henry Ford Museum, a top museum of national importance.  Southwest Detroit metro is not the worst place in America to kill a day **if you have a car**. It is the Motor City.

Comment: I got screwed really bad connecting in Denver to Manchester once. Had to go from B to A concourse, take the train and everything. They gave me 50 minutes, my flight in was delayed only 10. Didn't make it.

Answer (score 5):

In the US, there is no procedural difference between getting on a departing domestic flight and getting on a departing international flight. International flights can depart from the same waiting area and gates as domestic flights. So it's just a matter of which gates your first flight arrives at and your second flight departs at, and how far they are apart. From what I know, Detroit one main terminal with 3 concourses, and a separate North Terminal. If both your arriving and departing flights are in the same terminal, then a 1-hour layover should probably be okay.

Comment: Does that apply if the OP needs to collect and re-check baggage for the international flight? Allowing say 20mins for gate closure, that leaves just 40 minutes to de-plane, collect/recheck baggage and get to the gate

Comment: That’s applicable if the two flights are on the same ticket only, or maybe without checked luggage if online check-in is possible. Otherwise in my mind it’s probably impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Detroit doesn't have separate domestic and international sections. It does, however, have two terminals that are reportedly difficult to get between. Delta and AirFrance use the McNamara Terminal. All other airlines use the Evans Terminal. The McNamara Terminal is enormous, with three concourses (and the A concourse in particular is so long that there is a train to take you from one end to the other), so you could definitely spend 20-30 minutes going from one gate to another, but you should be able to make an hour connection within the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Detroit and use DTW as my primary airport.

In my opinion, the odds are good that you will make this connection. Why? Both flights should be in the McNamara terminal[1][2]. This assumes your first flight is on-time, and you hurry to the connecting flight.

I would call Delta to ask for seats near the front of the aircraft to help you deplane quickly, to aid this connection.

While other answers mention that McNamara Terminal is fairly large, it really is fairly quick to get around. Normally the trans-oceanic flights are near the middle, so probably won't need to go end-to-end.

[1] OP say flight with Delta from Miami to Delta; this should land in McNamara Terminal.

[2] The flight from DTW to AMS is probably with Delta or KLM; both of these depart from McNamara as well.